# CamelContext doesn't startup if one route is misconfigured

Tags: java, apache-camel

We use Java DSL to configure our routes. All configurations for routes are in a db table and can be configured via a GUI.

How is it possible to ensure that the `camelContext` starts up even if a route is misconfigured (e.g. `.to(invalidurl or typo)` in a route or simply a bug in a route)?

Is there a possibilty to validate the routes before starting or maybe better some parameters/options which can be set on the context itself?

Comment: Put the routes in separate contexts.

Comment: That's not an option for us. In our camel-context.xml we only have configured 1 context with a route builder. This route builder reads all routes + the configuration of the routes from the db. So we can't create here multiple contexts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure the routes with .autoStartup(false), and then start the routes manually when CamelContext has been started up.

To validate its really depending on what kind of component it is. If its some database component you can write some code that does a SQL query to see if the is valid user login or something.

To validate that an endpoint uri is misconfigured, then that is harder as they have a ton of options. But this is getting improved from Camel 2.16 onwards where we have during build time some tooling that generates a json schema file with the options, then we could potentially leverage that during parsing the routes to check for invalid configuration before attempting to create the endpoints which could detect errors sooner, and even also with IDE plugins or other 3rd party tooling.

Comment: I understand that it is hard to get a validation for all the components and all their options. Let's say I have 100 routes and add them to the context at startup and 1 is misconfigured(e.g. invalid to-endpoint in route), then all the other routes are not started, but this routes are all configured correctly. In my opinion there is no need for component based validation or something, I just need some kind of errorhandling that isolates the misconfigured route(or something like this)

Comment: yes but a spring app where you have mis configuration in a xml file would also fail on startup etc - its common practice to fail fast

Comment: I have thought about the fail fast practice, I think you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just before adding every route to the context, add it to a separate "test" context individually, and see if it spins up or fails; then based on that add it to your real context?