# Apache Camel Endpoint URI validation

Tags: apache-camel

When I got an error inside an Endpoint URI the camel context wont start.
It seems like Camel validates in a first step every Endpoint URI before starting the context.

Can someone pleas tell me, how this works?

Am I right?
I cant figure it out.

Comment: Potential duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620130/camelcontext-doesnt-startup-if-one-route-is-misconfigured

Comment: Thanks, I did not find that Post and it is similar to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Camel validates that it has been configured correctly when it startup. This happens as part of starting the Camel routes.

Its like misconfiguring any other software which will report an error for you to fix.

There is some tooling which you can use to validate your source code to find endpoints that has been misconfigured. I wrote a blog entry about this: http://www.davsclaus.com/2016/01/cheers-fabric8-camel-maven-plugin-to.html

Comment: One more question, it validates every Route in that context before starting it, right?
Sounds a bit like Design by Contract.

Comment: Yes every route is validated. However you can mark some of the routes to not automatic start, but they are still validated.